# Getting values selected from selects in list - Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

title says everything. I gotta do a relatively simple hybrid app in Ionic, and I want to get selected values in several ion-selects when a button is pressed. Here goes the code:

page.html

```
    <ion-content padding>

  <div id="sectionTitle"> </div>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let question of questions" (click)="itemSelected(question)">
      <ion-label>{{question.texto}} </ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <option ng-selected="selected">{{answers[0].texto}}</option>
        <ion-option text-wrap required *ngFor="let answer of answers; let i = index" onchange="itemSelected(answer)">
          <p> {{answer.text}} </p>
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <div class="sendButton">
  <button ion-button full type="submit" (click)="toComparisonPage()">
    Send
<!-- Here is where data must be retrieved -->
  </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
itemSelected(answer){
  console.log("Selected item: ");
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you specify an ngModel on your  tag.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItems">
```

in your page.ts you should then have a public variable declared and can access this.

`console.log(this.selectedItems);`

for more select configuration head up to the ionic documentation
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: for previous tries, I did specified an ngModel, but as these selects are created dynamicaly, I think they share that ngModel, so when 1 of them is modified, all of them change automatically :S

Comment: well you just can have an object/array and store your values in the appropriate index from the *ngFor.
for example:
`*ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index"`

and then use 
`ng-selected="selected[i]"`